# How to change the BackColor of Buttons inside a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tablelayoutpanel

Is there any way to change the background color of Buttons inside a TableLayoutPanel?

The background color of the Buttons will be changed with a click of a Button outside of the TableLayoutPanel.
Actually I wanted to know how to identify Buttons which are inside a TableLayoutPanel.
I am providing a code block below. Please correct me.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnClicked = sender as Button;
       // wanted to convert the controls of tablelayoutpanel
    if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls is Button)
    {
        btnClicked = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls;
    }
    else
        continue;
}

// Couldn't call the buttons inside the tablelayoutpanel.
```

Comment: Do you want to change the BackColor of all the Buttons inside a TLP or just some of them? One specific Button?

Comment: I would like to know about the both (All of the buttons as well as some specific buttons) inside a TLP. @Jimi

Comment: To change all the Buttons is not a problem at all. To change a specific subset of controls or a single one, you need to define the logic that allows to create a subset. For example, all the Buttons in the first Row/Column, or a Button that has a specific Text or Tag or Location or whatever fits.

Comment: Can you show me how to call all the buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control.Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls) is a collection. It cannot be cast to a single object. This:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls is Button
```

will be notified in the code editor (green underline) with the message:

> The given expression is never of the provided ('Button') type.

This cast will instead generate an error:

```
btnClicked = (Button)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls;
```

> CS0030:   Cannot convert type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutControlCollection' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

---

To modify a property of all Button controls child of a TableLayoutPanel (or any other container), you can enumerate its [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls) collection, considering only the child Controls of a specific Type.

For example, change to `Color.Red` the `BackColor` property of all Buttons inside a TableLayoutPanel:

```
foreach (Button button in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Change to `Text` property of all Buttons in the first Row:
Note that, here, I'm using a generic **`Control`** type instead of **`Button`**. This is because the `Text` property is common to all controls that derive from [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control). The `Text` property is defined in the `Control` class.

```
foreach (Control ctl in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (tlp1.GetRow(ctl) == 0)
        ctl.Text = "New Text";
}
```

Modify a property of a Control in the first Row, first Column of the TableLayoutPanel:
Here, I don't know what kind of control is located at coordinates `(0, 0)`, but I know it's an object derived from the Control class. So I can set a property that belongs to this class and is threfore inherited.
It may happen that a specific property is not relevant for a control Type. In this case nothing will happen (you can try to set the Text property of your TableLayoutPanel).

```
(tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0) as Control).BackColor = Color.Green;
```